# Laravel collection where clause

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Is possible in Laravel apply where condition to a collection and the result of that put in another collection without change the first one?

Ex:

```
$documenti = DB::table("RVW_DocumentiDettaglio")
                ->select("*")
                ->where("IDAzienda", "=", $request->session()->get("operatore.IDAzienda"))
                ->whereIn("CodiceStato", [Documento::E_DOC, Documento::W_DOC, Documento::OK_DOC])
                ->orderBy("IDDocumentoTestata", "asc");

// Ciclo le voci spesa
foreach ($voci_spesa as $voce_spesa) {
    Log_Controller::debug("Documenti:" . $documenti->get());

    if ($voce_spesa["Manuale"]) {
        $dettaglio = $documenti->where("Descrizione", "like", "%" . $voce_spesa["Descrizione"] . "%");
    } else {
        $dettaglio = $documenti->where("Descrizione", "=", $voce_spesa["Descrizione"]);
    }
    Log_Controller::debug("Dettaglio:" . $dettaglio->get());
}
die;
```

With `$documenti` I get the first collection, in the foreach I apply the where condition and put the result to `$dettaglio` collection, but the first one (`$documenti`) was also changed. Why? It's like shared object

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can certainly apply where clauses to Collections along with a good number of other methods including filtering and mapping. See the documentation here:

[Collections where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-where)

```
$collection = Item::all();

$filtered = $collection->where('price', 100);

$filtered->all();
```

Comment: Ok so first I have must to use ->get() method to extract collection, and then I can work to the first collection without change their's element even if I apply condiction to it? But what's the different if I use where condiction after or before get() method? The performance are the same?

Comment: Yep you can get a separate collection instance returned from those methods, leaving the original in tact. If you are only doing one thing to the collection after ->get(), I would say include the where() in the db query.

Comment: Not, after I do other things and all of that is under foreach loop, so I need to create for each loop a "duplicate" of the first collection

Comment: Then just assign it to a variable as soon as you finished the db query. $original = Model::all(); $copy = $original;